# Can you install Chrome browser on IOS devices to extend PWA support?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

KNowing that iOS devices has konky support for PWA features, I was wondering if installing chrome or other browsers on iOS can extend the features supported?

I know this isn't ideal for public/mass deployment apps, but for this particular project, it's internal use and we are able to require users to setup their iOS devices to work with our app.

So it's either we do this on PWA (we want to) or x-platform cordova or similar (we wanna move out of that)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on ios does not support installation of PWA. Check it [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20Progressive%20Web,faster%20access%20and%20additional%20functionality.&text=Chrome%20for%20iOS%20does%20not%20support%20PWAs.)

Answer (score 0):

Related to OP's question: installing PWA on iOS works in Safari.